# ExtJS 3.2.1 Combobox limit list items

Tags: extjs

I have a 30 element data array that gets put into my combobox.   I only want to display 5 items in the list and the user can scroll through the remaining items.   Is there a property I am overlooking that I can set to force this?

`indGrpField = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                fieldLabel: 'Industry Group',
                mode: 'local',
                renderTo: 'combos',
                store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                    fields: [
                               { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
                               { name: 'value', type: 'string' }
                    ]
                }),
                displayField: 'text',
                valueField: 'value',
                forceSelection: true,
                editable: false,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                width: 250,
                anchor: '100%'
            });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about setting the max to 5 items. But I'd try setting its `maxHeight`, that should do it.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-maxHeight